# awk script unable to parse field and save in variable

Tags: awk

```
➤ echo "host.example.com:      inet 10.242.177.24/24 brd"| awk '
{
        host=sub(/:/, "", $1);
        ip=sub(/\/.*/, "", $3);
        printf("%s, %s\n", $host, $ip);
}
'
host.example.com, host.example.com
```

I expect the output to be: `host.example.com, 10.242.177.24`.

I suspect there is something fundamentally wrong with it.

Comment: Yes, fundamentally. That is not proper awk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code commented:

```
$ echo "host.example.com:      inet 10.242.177.24/24 brd" | 
awk '{
        host=sub(/:/, "", $1);           # sub returns 1/0, 1 here 
        ip=sub(/\/.*/, "", $3);          # sub returns 1/0, 1 here
        printf("%s, %s\n", $host, $ip);  # this prints $1, $1
}
'
host.example.com, host.example.com
```

and fixed:

```
$ echo "host.example.com:      inet 10.242.177.24/24 brd" | 
awk '{
        sub(/:/, "", $1);                # sub replaces inplace 
        sub(/\/.*/, "", $3);             # sub replaces inplace
        printf "%s, %s\n", $1, $3        # proper printf
}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Awk is not bash. In awk variables are just `variables`. `$variable` is parsed as positional parameter `$<variable value>`. For example when `variable=1` then`$variable` means the same as `$1`.

The `sub` parses third argument and also places it's result int he third argument. `sub` returns the number of substitution made. So `host` becomes 1, because one `:` was substituted. And `host` is 1, so `$host` means the same as `$1`.

You could:

```
    sub(/:/, "", $1);
    sub(/\/.*/, "", $3);
    printf("%s, %s\n", $1, $3);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I've upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk:

```
echo "host.example.com:      inet 10.242.177.24/24 brd" | awk -F ':| +|/' '{print $1 ", " $4}'
```

Output:

```
host.example.com, 10.242.177.24
```